# Passing info from the page to the server in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django and I'm facing something pretty frustrating. There is an app that I've written a few months ago and I've recently decided to make it into a web application. I already have both client and server side written and working and I already set up the Django server to work. The only thing I'm struggling with is passing data from the page to the server.

I am able to transform info to the page in the views file using the code below, but I simply can't find a good explanation online on how to transfer info from the page to the server. I'm assuming its not a simply form-action like in classic HTML with other frameworks (like PHP), but its something that still should be relatively straight-forward and I'd be glad if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Here's the code I'm using in the app's views.py file to transfer data back to the page, but I need the 'info' string to be taken from the page first.

```
return render(request, "mypage.html", {'content':[imported function from my app]('info')}
```

Comment: Why wouldn't it be a "simple form action"? HTTP works the same no matter what backend language you are using.

Comment: In that case, what do I write under 'action' in the form? Just the name of the Python file? What about parameters that I need to pass?

Comment: No, the URL. All communication in web requests is done via URLs. Note, all this is well covered in the official tutorial, in this case [part 4](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial04/).

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for [request.POST](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.POST) maybe? Every data in the HTTP request is in the [HttpRequest](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#httprequest-objects) object.

Comment: It would seem so, but as I said I'm new to Django and I'm still trying to figure out how it all works. I have no idea how can I implement it to the HTML page and how do I process the data in the server later (where does it go and such).

Comment: Ok, then I would actually recommend reading the [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial04/) as @DanielRoseman recommended above.